# Use math equation input value to do math calculation in VBA Exccel

Tags: vba, excel, math, integral

I'm doing numerical integration in Excel VBA and I want to get the equation from the user instead of inserting it in the Cell.

Example

The user gives me x^3+x^2+2 which is F(X)

In A1, I have number 2 and I evaluate F(X) in B1.

How to tell excel that the equation input from user is =A1^3+A2^2+2. I just need that conversion to one cell.

I'm using Val(InputBox())

Thanks for the help

Comment: What code do you have so far? Please post it so a) we don't reinvent the wheel if you have code already, b) shows us what you've tried, and c) can find any potential errors.  I don't see how this should be too hard, since you're in VBA, just plug in the variable into the formula the user gives, no?

Comment: Why don't you just do what every math teacher tells us at school and replace `x` with the number in `A1`. Something like `Replace("x^3+x^2+2", "x", Range("A1").Value)`.

Comment: Nothing like a question about math equations in VBA on a Sunday morning to get the folks all riled up!

Comment: Actually Replace helped me out. Thanks for the reply Ralph!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user enters x or X and you only need to replace X with A1.cell.value then use this:

```
Sub test()
formula_user = InputBox("Please type formula")
Range("B1").Formula = "=" & Replace(LCase(formula_user), "x", "A1")
End Sub
```

x is replace with A1 in the formula from the user inputbox. It can be upper or lower case in the user input

Comment: THANKS A LOT! This helped to finish my Quantitative Methods Project jeje. Time to do the user's manual ajjaja

Comment: If the user writes exp(x)+2*x it results in eA1p(A1)+2*A1.

Comment: I found it, I'm going to tell the user/teacher that in case of using exponential formulas write the formula as EXP(x)+2*x. In that case I removed the LCase so the code differentiates the X and x

Answer (score 1):

The [Application Evaluate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) function can resolve the formula received from the user but you will have to find someway to convert **x** to a cell reference that can be correctly understood. This may require the worksheet name.

Your *x^3+x^2+2* example replaces two **x** values with A1 and A2. It may be better as *x^3+y^2+2* so that there is no ambiguity between what is A1 and what is A2.

```
Sub f_of_x_and_y()
    Dim fmla As String, str As String

    fmla = InputBox("enter formula")

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        str = Replace(Replace(fmla, "x", .Range("A1").Address(external:=True)), _
                                    "y", .Range("A2").Address(external:=True))
        .Range("A3") = Application.Evaluate(str)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if the user writes exp(x)+2*x

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub variable_input()
Dim userFormula$
Dim myVar&

myVar = 2
userFormula = InputBox("What is the formula?")
Debug.Print userFormula
userFormula = Replace(userFormula, "x", myVar)
Debug.Print userFormula

Dim theAnswer$
theAnswer = Val(userFormula)
Debug.Print theAnswer
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually this one will help the user to see the formula he wrote

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all "x" with the string "A1". Don't forget to add "=" in front...

```
Sub TestUserEquation()

    Dim strUserEquation As String

    strUserEquation = LCase(InputBox("Please enter your equation:", "Equation InputBox"))

    If strUserEquation <> "" Then
        Cells(1, 2) = "=" & Replace(strUserEquation, "x", "A1")
    Else
        Cells(1, 2) = "No equation entered."
    End If


End Sub
```